# calling golang println with variable arguments

Tags: go, println

I have the following code to print n lines for debug purposes. output() prints the address of args instead of the parameters. How to fix it ?

```
var outputMax = 10
var outputCnt = 0

func output(args ...interface{}) {
    outputCnt++
    if(outputCnt < outputMax) { println(args) }
}

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        output("Value of i is now:", i)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual way to call a varargs function would be like so:

```
func output(args ...interface{}) {
    println(args...)
}
```

However, this will give you a `invalid use of ... with builtin println` compilation error.  If you switch to `fmt.Println()` instead, it should work.